# Create a new list of values from attributes of objects in another list C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I work with a QList of objects mothers which has a QString attribute name. I want to create another list from mothers with only the names of the mothers.
This could be doing that:

```
QList<QString> names; 
for(int i=0; i<mothers.length<i++0{
   names[i] = mothers[i].name;
}
```

But I am wondering if I could do something more efficient.

Comment: "I work with a QList of objects mothers which has a QString attribute name." No, you don't. You work with objects that look like `struct Angle { double x, double y, double z };` and you intend to pass a collection of them to `QwtPlotCurve::setSamples` to plot only one of the fields. Until you amend your question to mention this ever important detail, I'm downvoting for blatantly making stuff up and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear since you're purposefully misleading and providing an unnecessary abstraction of the task at hand.

Comment: you are wasting your time saying that i am wasting your's. Peace. I am reposting that.

Comment: Duplicate questions are completely off-topic. I'm providing you with simple guidance as to how to improve this question: **edit** it to say what you meant to ask. If you're not asking about storing someone's names, don't pretend that you do. I am at a complete loss as to how you think this sort of distortion and abstracting out can help you. You are specifically asking about Qwt, too, so please add the qwt tag and the methods you wish to pass your data to, as well (I presume it's `setSamples`).

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you will need to iterate over one list and extract the names into the second list, that's unavoidable. It might be possible to make it look more tidy by using library methods or something similar to hide the loop, but those methods will still need to iterate over it.

So no, there isn't any more efficient way. Although, it's possible there are tidier ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed need a stand-alone list that has a copy of all the names, what you're doing is almost correct, except that you should reserve the storage in the target list, and use range-for construct:

```
QList<Mother> mothers;
...
QStringList names;
names.reserve(mothers.size());
// C++11
for (auto const & mother : mothers) names << mother.name;
```

For C++98, you'd fall back on:

```
for (QList<Mother>::const_iterator it = mothers.begin(); it != mothers.end(); ++it)
  names << it->name;
```

Do not be tempted to use `Q_FOREACH` or `foreach`, since those insist on making a copy of the entire `Mother` object on each iteration. The C++11 range-for is much more usable.

But, you might not really need that stand-alone list. Perhaps all you need is a pair of iterators that you could use to inspect the collection. You could make some iterator adaptors for that.

Comment: Thank you for the precision! helpfull!